# How to overwrite HTTP responses client-side in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, http, https, request

I am trying to return my own response to HTTP requests. For example, every request in the below code should return `"Custom Response"` followed by the URL.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
<script src="script.js"></script>
<img src="image.jpg"></script>

<script>
  fetch("data.json");

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "info.txt");
  xhr.send();
</script>
```

This should work by using something like:

```
document.addEventListener("overwritableRequest", function(request) {
  request.overwriteBody("Custom Response " + request.url);
});
```

Obviously, there isn't an event called `overwritableRequest`, but how would you replicate it using real APIs? For context, this functionallity only needs to work with requests over the same domain name.

### Research

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63867589/send-custom-response-to-xmlhttprequest-by-intercepting-at-client-side) and [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63864504/intercept-xmlhttprequest-and-send-a-promise) have similar goals to what I'm trying to achieve, but they don't answer how to overwrite requests from HTML elements, only `XMLHttpRequest` and `fetch`. Also, overwriting the functions seems hacky and inelegant. The only possible way that I could think of is to overwrite the elements using `document.querySelectorAll("[src]").forEach(e => e.src = "[file with custom contents]")` and `document.querySelectorAll("link[href]").forEach(e => e.href = "[file with custom contents]")`, but you would have to manually go through each case (fixing bugs with other elements, implementing more elements, etc.), and it [still wouldn't work with `script`s](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55097811/change-script-src-before-dom-is-rendered-using-js). You could also use a backend server to overwrite requests, but the website is static (the backend is basically just a file server). Because of all of these drawbacks, is there any basic function or event to cover all of these cases?

Comment: You could try this with a service worker: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers